# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting the following error while trying to do a BGR to binary threshhold conversion.

> imgthreshhold = cv2.inRange(img, cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125),
>   cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255)) AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'cv'

Following is the complete program.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#help(cv2)
while cap.isOpened():
    #BGR image feed from camera
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('output', img)
    #BGR to grayscale
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('grayscale', img2)
    #BGR to binary(RED) thershholded
    imgthreshhold = cv2.inRange(img, cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125), cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255))
    cv2.imshow('threshholded', imgthreshhold)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: is it not cv2.Scalar rather than cv2.cv.Scalar?

Comment: No in the tutorial I follow it's said that it has to be referred back to opencv version 1

Comment: What version of OpenCV do you use ?

Comment: But lets say I don't know your version of OpenCV. You should remove the `cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125)` and make it just `[3,3,125]` and similarly the second one. Remember to `import numpy as np`

Comment: Osama Abbas, when I tried  imgthreshhold = cv2.inRange(img, [3,3,125], [40,40,255]) I got the following error :(
TypeError: lowerb is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: cv2.__version__ gives me 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing the same issue. And I think we are following the same tutorial for OpenCV. I messed around with the function a little, and found that only providing the values worked fine.

So this is how your code should look like:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#help(cv2)
while cap.isOpened():
    #BGR image feed from camera
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('output', img)
    #BGR to grayscale
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('grayscale', img2)
    #BGR to binary(RED) thershholded
    imgthreshhold = cv2.inRange(img, (3,3,125), (40,40,255))
    cv2.imshow('threshholded', imgthreshhold)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```